# Postgtres: Calculate number of days as float considering hours/minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, timestamp

I would like to compute the number of days since `1899/12/30`, taking into consideration the number of hours and minutes.

So, for example data in my table:

```
+--------------------+-------------+
|     dob            |    n_days   |
+--------------------+-------------+
|1980-08-09 13:34:10 |  29442.5654 |
|2005-12-15 23:10:00 |  38701.6528 |
|2020-02-26 15:56:00 |  43887.6639 |
+--------------------+-------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', dob -'1899-12-30 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ) AS n_days 
FROM my_date;
```

Returns only whole day count:

```
n_days
---------
29441
38701
43887
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
extract(epoch from dob - '1899-12-30 00:00:00'::timestamptz) / 60 / 60 / 24
```

Rationale:

- the timestamp substraction gives you an `interval` that represents the difference between the timestamps
- `extract(epoch from ...)` turns this to a number of seconds
- all that is left to do is divide by the number of seconds that there is in a day

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=774fa7dd710e9bb88d831ddedcded2c1)**:

```
with t as (
    select '1980-08-09 13:34:10'::timestamptz dob
    union all select '2005-12-15 23:10:00'::timestamptz
    union all select '2020-02-26 15:56:00'::timestamptz
)
select 
    dob,
    extract(epoch from dob - '1899-12-30 00:00:00'::timestamptz) / 60 / 60 / 24 as n_days
from t
```

```
dob                    | n_days            
:--------------------- | :-----------------
1980-08-09 13:34:10+01 | 29442.52372685185 
2005-12-15 23:10:00+00 | 38701.965277777774
2020-02-26 15:56:00+00 | 43887.66388888889
```

Comment: Thank you, I see the logic.

Comment: @super_ask . . . Just a note:  This works for all days ON OR AFTER 1900-03-01, because Excel format messes up on whether 1900 is a leap year.  Incidentally, this is why the base date is 1899-12-30 rather than 1899-12-31.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I actually did wonder why it was Dec 30th instead of 31st!

Comment: The dataset I'm using uses number of days from that date.